# how to create an excel built in userform

Tags: vba, excel, user-interface, userform

how can I create this kind of built in userform in excel? I am learning Visual Basic but couldn't find a way of creating a userform which is build in a sheet of excel like this picture.

[image: EXCEL USER FORM]

Comment: Here is a [**link to a tutorial**](http://www.contextures.com/xlUserForm01.html).  It's a series of videos and then further instruction, looks fairly thorough, and is probably a good place for you to start.  **Note** that the first video is just an overview of what UserForms *can* do.  The instruction starts in the *second* video ("part one").  If you're not already comfortable with basic use of Excel worksheets, you'll need to start there before diving into UserForms VBA.

Comment: To get you started, read this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-forms-form-controls-and-activex-controls-on-a-worksheet-15ba7e28-8d7f-42ab-9470-ffb9ab94e7c2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is about Excel 5.0 dialog sheets. To create a dialog sheet, right-click any worksheet tab. From the pop-up menu, select Insert, and on the General tab of the Insert dialog box, select MS Excel 5.0 Dialog. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2012/03/05/customizing-your-messages-with-dialog-sheets/) is some more information on it

Comment: Thank you it's excactly what I was asking for!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - create a userform like this:

[image]

Step 2 - write this code in the worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Step 3 - keep reading, there are many other better ways to do it - [Best Practices for User Forms in the Ex-StackOverflow Documentation.](http://www.riptutorial.com/vba/example/19036/best-practices)

Comment: i think you misunderstood his question

Comment: @Banana - it makes exactly what the op wants - a VBA form in the worksheet.

Comment: @Vityata Not really. It creates a userform separate from the worksheet, not in it, which is what the op was asking for. To achieve the latter, you need to embed form controls/ActiveX objects in the given sheet.

Comment: @Miqi180 - it is separate, but it looks like the one from the screenshot of the op, I guess.

Comment: A pop-up userform like yours has a close button ('X') in the top right corner and the screenshot doesn't show one. However, since the OP is silent on this, I guess he doesn't really want to be helped...

Comment: Thanks to everybody! It's Excel 5.0 dialog sheet. I had to insert it via right-click on any worksheet tab.